# What size a/c should be used with whole-house dehumidifier?

Tags: air-conditioning, dehumidifier

I have a whole-house dehumidifier (WHD) to control R/H in the basement as well as on the main level of my house (with separate controls). Does that mean a smaller or larger A/C would be more efficient? I live in south-central Indiana, which has fairly hot and humid summers, but I use the WHD also in the colder seasons to some extent. I like to keep the temperature at 78 deg. or higher for A/C. I can see how a smaller A/C could be better since it has less work to do; I can see how a larger one would be better in getting the temperature to change more quickly without worrying about dehumidification. Or are the differences so small that it does not matter? The main level is about 1500 sq ft; the basement is not conditioned. My question concerns not the absolute size of the A/C, but only relative to what I would have without the WHD.

Comment: How many square feet is your house? People will need to know this, at a minimum, to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

It would be unwise to under size an AC unit in an area that has hot and humid summers just because you have a WHD. Each unit has a separate function so let each one do it's job. The basement will need the dehumidifier more than the first floor especially if there's no AC down there and will be needed all year around as you've already mentioned. Your AC should be sized based on your square footage and possibly the cu-ft of space if you've got high ceilings. The last thing you want is to have an under sized AC unit when you're having a heat wave, which happens a lot in your area.

Comment: Your AC should be sized based on the building's Manuel J, fullstop +1. You also don't want it oversized or it will cool the air before it drops the moisture out, which promotes mold and bacteria. - What size *dehumidifier* should be used with whole-house AC? None (that's what they do), otherwise the AC wasn't sized properly, or you have an especially dank basement that no matter what will need a separate device... because it's not in the envelope ("basement is not conditioned").